# Visual Studio 2015- How to disable "based on your project, we have identified extensions you may find helpful" message?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Since the latest update to Visual Studio 2015, I get this message when I open `.html` or `.cshtml` files. Clicking "Don't Ask Again" only disables this until VS is restarted. How can I turn it off permanently?

[image]

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can disabled this by going to `Tools > Options > Text Editors > HTML > Advanced` and setting `Identify Helpful Extensions` to `False`.

An easy way to get there is to type `html adv` in the quick launch:

[image]

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4bc107df-0f0f-4b05-bc8e-e84dc75e2f2c/visual-studio-2015-community-based-on-your-project-we-have-identified-extensions-you-might-find?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Comment: Thanks, pitiful they waste time making and we waste time turning such dumb features off.

Answer (score 21):

My experience was clicking the "Don't Show Again" link toggled the Tools > Options > Text Editors > HTML > Advanced > Identify Helpful Extensions: to False, but it did not save that setting when exiting VS. So, be sure to manually toggle that setting to make it stick.